# jQuery dataTables : trouble getting full_numbers pagination to display correctly in IE

Tags: jquery, css, pagination, datatables

I'm using the jQuery plugin DataTables (http://www.datatables.net/) with the following initialization:

```
$('#reconcile_table').dataTable( {
'bSort'          : true,
'bFilter'        : true,
'bSortClasses'   : false,
'iDisplayLength' : 200,
'bPaginate'      : true,
'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
'bProcessing'    : true,
'sDom'           : '<"top"pf>rt<"bottom"i><"clear"l>'
});
```

I'm using the 'full_numbers' pagination with styling. With my CSS styling code it looks good in Firefox, but in IE the paging navigation buttons are reduced to just a sliver, like they've been clipped somehow.

I can't use an image as I'm a new user, so I'm kinda stuck there to explain myself further. Any help about what's going on in IE would be most appreicated, as I can't figure it out myself! :)

Thanks,
Doug

Comment: Probably too late to help, but you may have luck with the forum at http://datatables.net/

Answer (score 2):

... better late than never; I think you may have an error with your "padding" properties in the CSS. IE handles padding very differently to FF, especially if it thinks the element is "empty".

Try adding a width and height attribute to the pagination links in your CSS. Hope that helps you out.